# QAction Triggered Signal to pass parameter to Slot

Tags: qt

So say i have this where QDataTable is a QTableWidget

```
QAction* copyDataAction = new QAction("Copy Data");
DataTable->addAction(copyDataAction);
connect(copyDataAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(CopyTableData()));
```

This works fine and the CopyTableData slot gets called, but say i wanted to get a reference to DataTable to CopyTableData(), so that CopyTableData could be generic and i could pass any QTableWidget* pointer i want.

If i do

```
connect(copyDataAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(CopyTableData(DataTable)));
```

Obviously the slot never gets called, i feel like this is a simple problem i just dont know what im missing.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to use a lambda function with the same amount of inputs so that the signal will trigger properly, but use that to locally pass the dataTable that i want to the function.

```
connect(copyDataAction, &QAction::triggered, this, [=](){
        CopyTableData(DataTable);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender

```
connect(copyDataAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(CopyTableData()));

void Myclass::CopyTableData()
{
   DataTable* td = qobject_cast<DataTable *>(QObject::sender());
   if(td)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```